# displaying data from selected rows in datagridview into a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Im trying to display data from datagridview into a textboxes of another form. The form 2 has textboxes. Here is my code:

```
private void btnAddOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Add_Order addOrder = new Add_Order();
    addOrder.
}
```

Im trying to type `addOrder.textBox1.Text = dtgv_Items.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();` but `textBox1` that should automatically appear is not displaying, meaning there's an error. How could I solve this? :)

Comment: @coder - it's the name of the form 2 :)

Comment: possible solutions: 1) you can make any control (in your case `textBox1`) on a form with `public` modifiers, so you can then access them if you have access to the form instance 2) many forms can access same data source and they don't even need to know about each other 3) provide a special mechanism to supply information (in your case selected cells) via event, public or public static property, manager class...

Comment: @rr_only4you - `addorder.textBox1.text` after the `addorder` the `textbox1` should automatically appeart but it doesnt

Comment: @Sinatr - how will I do that? :)

Comment: @lexter, in the form designer select control (`textBox1`), find in properties `Design - Modifiers`, change from `Private` to `Public`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for any selected cell:

Form2:

```
private string pVal;

//getter and setter
public string PassVal
{
    get { return pVal; }
    set { pVal = value; }
}

//or event that you need
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = pVal;
}
```

Form1:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();

int selectedCellCount = dataGridView1.GetCellCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);

if (selectedCellCount > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedCellCount; i++)
    {
        int column = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i].ColumnIndex;
        int row = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i].RowIndex;
        f2.PassVal = dataGridView1[column, row].Value.ToString();
    }
}

f2.Show();
```

with this peace of code you'll get text from any selected cell in your textbox.

hope it helped you a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

use the textbox it self direct

```
textBox1.Text = dtgv_Items.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: textBox1 is on the other form that's why i declared it first. `Add_Order addorder = new Add_Order();`

Comment: To get and set the value of a textbox within another class/form you can do it with something like:

public string TextBox1Text
{ get { return textBox1.Text; } 
  set { textBox1.Text = value; } }

Answer (score 0):

First, create getter and setter on the second form.

```
private string sampleData = string.Empty;

public string SampleData
{
    get { return sampleData; }
    set { value = sampleData; }
}
```

Then you can use this on your first form:

```
private void btnAddOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Add_Order addOrder = new Add_Order();
    addOrder.SampleData = dtgv_Items.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
}
```

To view the result on your second form, use this:

```
this.TextBox1.Text = SampleData;
```